# C# How to pause program

Tags: c#, timer

I have simple question. How do I pause program? I want to change pictures very slowly.

My code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Image picture1 = Program.Properties.Resources.picture1;
Image picture2 = Program.Properties.Resources.picture2;
Button1.Image = picture1
//Here I want pause
Button1.Image = picture2
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean with pause a program?

Comment: I mean something like Timer or stuff. I want just change button image then wait for few seconds then change it again.

Comment: You probably *don't* want to pause, as in you don't want to completely lock up your application and make it unresponsive. What you probably *do* want to do is use a timer to execute some code after some period of time while you application continues to work in the meantime. [Hint: lookup timer on MSDN]

Comment: For WPF you'll want to look at [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) for Winforms you'll want [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Other timers also exist, but these are the two easiest to use because their tick event happens in the UI thread.

Comment: For a one time pause you can insert `    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(1234);` before the 2nd image ist set; this is quite a bit hackyish.. But for a real image animation do look up Timer and its Tick event!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want procedural code (like in your example), without timers and without locking the UI:

```
await Task.Delay(1000)
```

Comment: it sounds great but i have got error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: @Kuri Is the message not clear? `Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

Comment: @Kuri If you never used async/await before, I recommend reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use Threads or Timers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx

http://programmingbaba.com/how-to-stop-system-threading-timer-in-c-do-net/

Or you can use Sleep method to puase your program.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sleep

Comment: OP is not using threads, and as with other answer you don't want to sleep on a UI. Timers is ok IMO.

Comment: Well, you can try with a Timer

Comment: Yes, that is my point, a Timer is ok, but the other two things you linked are for threads- ie unrelated. Also you didn't elaborate on anything- this 'answer' should be a comment.